# "How does this look ON the outside." OR "How does this look FROM the outside."?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions

A native english speaker says this, when she is showing what is inside her bag. She takes things out one by one, talks about each of them, put them on a table, etc. She says:

**"Do I look supermessy. How does this look on the outside"?** [Vogue-What is inside my bag](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HEXDJCgUgE)(see:1:40-1:50)

The expression **"..... ON the outside"** caught my attention. Shouldn't it be **"....FROM the outside."?**

Comment: Both are OK. Strictly, 'on the outside' might be more about the external aspect of something (its skin, coating, external decoration, etc) and 'from the outside' might be more about the view or opinion of someone external to the thing or situation. However native speakers may be careless or indifferent about such a distinction (especially those who are not grammarians or linguists).

Comment: Tried a dictionary? [Longman's](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/on-the-outside), [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20the%20outside),

Comment: @StuartF, I almost always make a research before asking, but dictionaries usually give the meaning of a phrase, and leave it at that. They don't tell you what the difference would be, if any, when another similar usage also exists. For example, the dictionary does not explain "from the outside" at all, whereas it is also commonly used, which is what confuses us learners. Also, we get perplexed when we see something - explained in a dictionary- yielding on google search almost 1/40000 less hits than the other alternative.

Comment: @StuartF prepositions are notoriously hard to define.  On top of that, none of the definitions for "on the outside" given by either of the dictionaries you link to seems to apply to the use in the video, and neither dictionary glosses "from the outside," so it's not immediately clear whether we can justify either phrase from its component parts based on their dictionary definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without context, I'd expect "how does this bag look on the outside" to be a question about the appearance of the outer surface of the bag, whereas "...from the outside" describes the position of the observer, so is a bit nonsensical for a bag.  You might use it for a house, a town, or even figuratively for an organization.

In the context of the video, it does seem as though she's asking about how she appears to outside observers, or about hoe the situation appears to outside observers, so I too would prefer "from the outside."  But prepositions are rather unstable over time and space, so I would stop well short of saying that it's wrong to use "on."